# How to call a form to be displayed in main content of a page without page reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

I have a page that is based on my master page. the code below

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CaseAdmin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Prototype4.CaseAdmin" %>
<%@PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Account/Login.aspx"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="CaseRightNews" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightNewsItem" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="CaseLeftNav" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftNavigation" runat="server">

    <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="OpenCaseLinkButton" runat="server" 
            onclick="OpenCaseLinkButton_Click">Open Case</asp:LinkButton> </p>
    <p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="RegisterExhibitLinkButton" runat="server">Register Exhibit</asp:LinkButton> </p>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="CaseMainContnt" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

when the page above loads, i have link buttons on the left and an empty maincontent area next to its right. what i want to do is display an entry form in the main content on click event of the link button on the left. the second form is as below.(form not based on master page).

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OpenCase.aspx.cs" Inherits="Prototype4.EntryForms.OpenCase" %>
<%@PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/CaseAdmin.aspx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .casePage
        {
            width: 430px;
            height:314px;
            background-color:#3a4f63;
        }
        .style1
        {
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .style2
        {
            font-weight: normal;
            color: Black;
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top:0px;

        }
        .style3
        {
            width: 85%;
        }
        .style4
        {
            width: 175px;
            background-color: #808080;
        }
        .style5
        {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
            padding-left:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="casePage">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 313px; width: 430px">
    <h2 class="style1">
        <strong>Open Case
        Form</strong></h2>
    <div style="width: 426px; margin-bottom:20px;">


        <table class="style3" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    <p class="style2">
                    Case ID:    
                    </p>
            </td>
                <td class="style5">
            <asp:TextBox ID="caseIDTextBox" 
                runat="server" height="22px" width="154px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    <p class="style2">
                    Case Description:
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="caseDescTextBox" 
                runat="server" height="22px" width="154px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                   <p class="style2">
                    Case Administrator ID:
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:TextBox 
                ID="caseAdminIDTextBox" runat="server" height="22px" width="154px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>






            </div>
            <div>


                <table class="style3" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Button ID="openCaseBotton" runat="server" Text="Open Case" 
                                onclick="openCaseBotton_Click" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Button ID="addExhibitBotton" runat="server" Text="Add Exhibit" 
                                onclick="addExhibitBotton_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

how do i perform this task?

and if i wanted to display a different form in place of the first one that appeared in the maincontent area, how do i go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web requests without page reloads are usually done with Javascript, called AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). You can do this with regular Javascript, but a library like jQuery (http://jquery.com/) makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for your response...very helpful...could you please recommend and active links where i can easily learn how to implement this using the jQuery? i may not know anything about javascripts, XMl nor jQuery but i cant be that dumb to apply it from a very intuitive explanation...

Comment: this is what i have done so far after reading about it on msdn.

Comment: I would also recommend the W3c schools tutorials... they are pretty good and simple.. www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use MS AJAX, place the maincontent area inside an UpdatePanel and set the LinkButtons as Triggers for the UpdatePanel using the AsyncPostBackTrigger tag of the UpdatePanel.

There are some simple tutorials (added, link was previously blocked)

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Comment: Thanks Lloyd, Id be very grateful if you can provide some active links that can demonstrate how i can apply MS AJAX, and AsyncPostBack ...

Comment: My link buttons are in a the leftnav content holder while my update panel and trigger is in my maincntent content holder. how do i reference the link buttons from the leftnav content? more clarity shown in the code below....

Comment: Code for left nav content is as follows: <asp:Content ID="CaseLeftNav" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftNavigation" runat="server">

    <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <p class="actionButton">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="OpenCaseLinkButton" runat="server" 
            onclick="OpenCaseLinkButton_Click">Open Case</asp:LinkButton> 
    </p>
    <p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="RegisterExhibitLinkButton" 
            runat="server" onclick="RegisterExhibitLinkButton_Click">Register Exhibit</asp:LinkButton> </p>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

Comment: And code for maincntent content :<asp:Content ID="CaseMainContnt" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="CaseMainCntntUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OpenCaseLinkButton" eventname="Click"/>
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                what goes here?                               
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        
</asp:Content>